# Ways to manually install setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, setuptools

I'm on windows and want to use python and a few packages, however, due to our policies it is not possible to have admin rights and any fetch requests done by pip (or any other package manager I'd assume) are being blocked.

So far I've downloaded Python (3.9.6) and "installed" it by manually unzipping and setting the PATH env variable.
I know that packages can be manually downloaded and installed as well using setup.py, however I also do not have setuptools, so is there any way to manually install that?

Answer (score 0):

**pip doesn't require admin rights** just use it with `--user`.If you want to avoid using `pip` here the steps

if the folder has setup.py in it

1. Download the packages and uncompress if needed open folder
2. holding shift click open with cmd or powershell
3. run `python setup.py install --user` or `python3 setup.py install --user`

if not present setup.py check the install documentation provided by module.

Comment: I cannot install pip as any fetch within get-pip.py is being blocked by our network and I don't know how to install setuptools without pip, hence I cannot execute any setup.py

Comment: just download the [setup tools source code](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/archive/refs/tags/v57.4.0.zip)   and do the second step

Comment: I hope you have [python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) in the path env variable.

Comment: I did, but when executing setup.py of setuptools sourcecode, it tells me that it requires setuptools to run